# Flutter: how do I either call a function inside a state class OR access a state class attribute?

Tags: function, flutter, state, stateful

From the StatefulWidget class, I want to call a function within the State class as such:

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget{

  // access _ParentState: iWantToAccessThis
  // OR
  // run from _ParentState: iWantToRunThis

  @override
  _ParentState createState() => new _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent>{
  List<Object> iWantToAccessThis;
  void iWantToRunThis(){
    // do something
  }
  ...
}
```

UPDATE: found a work around by making my list a static list.  Since there is going to always be one version of the list, this will work.  However, I'd still like a proper answer for running functions within a state or accessing attributes that aren't lists or static (though I'm leaning towards it being impossible to access non-static attributes).

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget{

  static void _getList(){
    _ParentState._iWantToAccessThis;
  }

  @override
  _ParentState createState() => new _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent>{
  static List<Object> _iWantToAccessThis;
  List<Object> get iWantToAccessThis => _iWantToAccessThis;
  ...
}
```

Comment: That is purely impossible. The widget part _cannot_ access its state

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? If you want to do some initialisation the state class has initState method.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this, but I wouldn't recommend it

```
class _MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State state;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    state = _MyWidgetState();
    return state;
  }
}
```

I think there can be another ways to solve your problem, then access to state from widget